# añadir un botón a un componente desde otro componente en react native

Tags: react-native

tengo el componente Child.js que es llamado desde App.js, y otro componente Work25.js. necesito que desde un botón de Child.js se quiten los dos botones de Child.js y se muestren 3 botones de Work25.js

Child.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { Stopwatch, Timer } from 'react-native-stopwatch-timer';
import Work25 from './Work25';


const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});




 class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isTimerStart: false,
        isStopwatchStart: false,
        resetTimer: false,
        resetStopwatch: false,
        totalDuration: 1500000,
        cambiarBoton: false


      };
      this.startStopTimer = this.startStopTimer.bind(this);
      this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
      this.startStopStopWatch = this.startStopStopWatch.bind(this);
      this.resetStopwatch = this.resetStopwatch.bind(this);
      this.work25start = this.work25start.bind(this);


    }
    startStopTimer() {
      this.setState({isTimerStart: !this.state.isTimerStart, resetTimer: false});


    }


    resetTimer() {
      this.setState({isTimerStart: false, resetTimer: true});
    }

    startStopStopWatch() {
       this.setState({isStopwatchStart: !this.state.isStopwatchStart, resetStopwatch: false});




    }

    resetStopwatch() {
      this.setState({isStopwatchStart: false, resetStopwatch: true});

    }

    getFormattedTime(time) {
        this.currentTime = time;
    }

    work25start(){
       this.setState({});
    }

    render() {
      return (


          <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:32, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Timer totalDuration={this.state.totalDuration} laps minutes start={this.state.timerStart}
              start={this.state.isStopwatchStart}
              //To start
              reset={this.state.resetStopwatch}
              //To reset
              options={options}
              //options for the styling
              getTime={this.getFormattedTime} />
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.startStopStopWatch}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginTop:10}}>
                 {!this.state.isStopwatchStart ? "START" : "STOP"}



              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.resetStopwatch}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginTop:10}}>RESET</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>



      );
    }

}
```

desde el siguiente boton

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.startStopStopWatch}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginTop:10}}>
                 {!this.state.isStopwatchStart ? "START" : "STOP"}



              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
```

como hago para mostrar los botones de Work25.js? supongo que usando los estados y props. Tengo que en Work25.js poner los botones como props? y con un 
estado.

```
this.state = {
botonplay: false,
botoncancelar: false
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.blablabla}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginTop:10}}>CANCELAR</Text>
                  {this.props.cancelar}
              </TouchableHighlight>
```

soy nuevo con react native y aun no entiendo la logica de los componentes.

Comment: o es mejor cambiar el renderizado de la aplicación mostrando Work25.js y quitando Child.js? usando los ciclos de vida willmount etc...?

Comment: Puedes poner un flag, y segun lo que vale el flag, mostrar el componende Child.js o Work.js